How to add custom domain to multiple internal container apps
The scenario is that I want to set up multiple internal container apps under the same container apps environment. All these apps are in the same VNET.
I understand that to access them, I need to create a private DNS zone to map domains like:
https://test1.apple-1234.northeurope.azurecontainerapps.io/
https://test2.bigapple-5678.northeurope.azurecontainerapps.io/

...to their internal IP addresses.
My question is: how can I set up internal domains for the above apps? For example, I would like to access these two apps using:
http://test1.xyz.abc
http://test2.xyz.abc

P.S. These domains are only used internally and will only be accessed within the VNET.

Have you tried any approach for your requirement?

@VenkatV I did try add xyz.abc to the custom domain, but it doesn't work as I cannot pass the validation step (xyz.abc is not a real domain name of course)

Check this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/custom-domains-certificates and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli#dns

I hope this helpful to resolve your issue.


How to add custom domain to multiple internal container apps

There is no validation required for your custom domain when adding or attaching a domain in Container Apps. Follow the MS Doc for more details


Add the custom domain to your container app using the full domain instead of xyz.abc, as shown below

    EX: my app name is  theja-container-app
    Custom domain is : theja-container-app.xyz.abc

Custom domain configuration


Note: Make sure to restart the container app after adding the custom domain.


Check the settings below in your application. If they are not as shown, update the settings.



Create a private DNZ zone with virtual link.



Create an A record for your application with the static IP of the container app environment in the private DNS zone.


Container apps environment static IP


Add the local host entry on your VM

 10.0.0.159     demo-container-app.mangosea-d4264213.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io
 10.0.0.159     theja-container-app.mangosea-d4264213.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io

Local host entry

Result from my VM which has same Vnet as container app



Thanks, it works as you suggested.
The only thing for people who see this page is "PLEASE IGNORE THE STAUS - 'No biding'" when you add the custom domains.
